# Add or Append section with rows on top of tableView data values Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, delegates

I have created a DataList in `UITableView` with sections and rows. Plus I have implemented delegate function for `add & delete` functions. Actually I need to add or append new `section` and `row` value which is selected. My first model is `PickListData` and then other sections values retrieving from `Item` -> `pickList`.

Model Hierarchy: `PickListData` -> `let items: [Item]?` -> `var pickList: [SectionList]?` -> `textField`

I implemented `func didAddnewRow(_ sender: UIButton)` but its adding row within the section and I need new section on top with name of `Selected`.

- Issue is how to put `Section` **Selected** and row which is selected from below sections.

Images attached current and actual I want to implement.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add a new section before adding a row to that section. After inserting “Selected” section, the "A. Items" section will be moved down.

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return AppData?.pickList?.count ?? 0
    }



 func sectionIndexTitles(for tableView: UITableView) -> [String]? {

  return [“Selected", “A. Items"]
}




 func didAddnewRow(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if let cell = sender.superview?.superview as? DictionaryTableViewCell,
        let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPath(for: cell) {

        if let selectedItem = AppData?.pickList?[indexPath.section].items?[indexPath.row] {

            let insertIndexPath = IndexPath(item: AppData?.pickList?[0].items?.count ?? 0, section: 0)


    if !AppData?.pickList.contains(where: {$0.title == “Selected" }) {


   AppData?.pickList.append(SectionList(title: “Selected”, items: selectedItem))

   tableView.insertSections(IndexSet([selectedItem]), with: .automatic)

    } else {

      AppData?.pickList?[0].items?.append(selectedItem)
  }


            cell.btnAdd.isHidden = true
            cell.btnDelete.isHidden = false
            tableView.beginUpdates()

            tableView.insertRows(at: [insertIndexPath], with: .automatic)
            tableView.endUpdates()

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: First of all thank you. Error I got `The number of sections contained in the table view after the update (2) must be equal to the number of sections contained in the table view before the update (2), plus or minus the number of sections inserted or deleted (1 inserted, 0 deleted).' `

Comment: I updated tableView code and added `func numberOfSections ` code.

Comment: its not working plus how can I give name to selective section to `Selected` ?

Comment: `func sectionIndexTitles ` only prints indexes. First thing is section is not added, I pasted the error for this.

Comment: Where is the data source for AppData.pickList ? insert the section in tableView only when you append to AppData.pickList array. The `sectionIndexTitles` is used to set section titles

Comment: this is my data source.  `var AppData: Item?`

Comment: I modified `didAddnewRow` , try and see if it works

Comment: Ok I am implementing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207843/discussion-between-newbie-and-k4747z).

Comment: I will look it up this coming week

Comment: even right now I am trying to add section and using various ways to add but not successful.

Comment: I have just little update the code. Section is now adding but its printing at last of tableView when I use `tableView.reload()` but duplicate. I used `print(AppData)`. check updated image.

Comment: Hi, have you got any chance ?

Comment: Hi , I think it might be because you’re appending a new section and not delete the old one

Comment: Did you try using tableView.moveRow(at: <#T##IndexPath#>, to: <#T##IndexPath#>) yet? I looking at your project.

Comment: Thank you. No I haven't use tableView.moveRow.

Comment: if you have any questions please do let me know. Thanks

Comment: any success regarding this ?